# Push notification opening the service-worker instead of the url on Android in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

It opens the passed URL fine in Chrome on PC, but when it's get clicked on Android it opens up the service-worker?

//service-worker

```
self.addEventListener("push",    function(event) {

    const data = event.data.json();

    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title,
            {
                body: data.body,
                icon: data.icon,
                tag: data.tag,
                data: {
                    url: data.url
                }
            })
    );
});


self.addEventListener("notificationclick",function(event) {

    event.notification.close();
    return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url);

});
```

Comment: this doesnt look native Android, is this xamarin or cordova?

Comment: can you add to the tags what language did you used?

Comment: @noogui this is pure JS service-worker meant to be running in chrome